# How to completely remove vitualenv?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying out stuff with Python and have created a virtualenv on directory "my-example". Now I want to get rid of it. Will simply deleting it be enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove/delete a virtualenv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005457/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question...

Comment: Yes, it does! The answer is yes, deleting the directory is enough.