# rmvirtualenv <name> does not remove a env

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am a beginner in Python.

I am trying to remove a virtualenv which I have created before by using this command under C:>virtualenvs

```
rmvirtualenv test
```

and then I got the following

virtualenv "test" does not exist.

I still can see the directory listed under virtualenvs. I am on windows platform and have already installed virtualwrapper-win.

Please suggest how can I get rid of that env using the above command.

Comment: are you sure you created the virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005457/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-virtualenv

Comment: @mic4ael No I don't. That virtual environment was created first and then I installed virtualenvwrapper directly under C drive.

Comment: @Harrison Thanks for the link.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks a lot both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out this issue.

Considering you have already installed virtualenvwrapper-win(if Windows)

The steps are --

```
1.Go to directory 'virtualenvs' (where all the envs are listed)
2.Make an env by using this command -- mkvirtualenv test (where test is a env name in my case)
3. Use this command  -- workon test
4. Deactivate test
5. To remove test use this command -- rmvirtualenv test
```

That's it.