# How do I uninstall Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface?

Tags: pip, windows-10, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently ran the following command to install the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI).  I would now like to remove it from my Windows 10 machine.

```
C:\Users\Cale>pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli
```

What is the best command to run to ensure that its fully removed from my machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to uninstall using the following command:

```
C:\Users\Cale>pip uninstall awsebcli
```

I was uncertain how to do the uninstall since I specified `--user` in the original install command.  This stackoverflow article helped me understand that the `--user` option would not matter during the uninstall process.

[How to uninstall a package installed with pip install --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `awsebcli` is not present in the `pip list` command that references the $PATH. I get this error:

> Skipping awsebcli as it is not installed.

Apparently, it's on the `pip` executable(s) in this location (Windows, PowerShell format):

```
$env:userprofile\.ebcli-virtual-env\Scripts\
```

The uninstall command worked properly using one of those executables.

After that, it it seems that deleting the `.ebcli-virtual-env` will remove it fully from the machine: [How do I remove/delete a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005457/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-virtualenv) (disclaimer: I'm not a pythonista :) )