# How do I remove pyenv virtualenvs

Tags: python, terminal, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

How do I go about removing all these virtual environments? I don't know where the directories are

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005457/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-virtualenv

Comment: Yes. I don't know where these virtualenv's directories are. All I know about them is what they are called.

Comment: Are you on windows or linux ?

Comment: Neither, I'm on mac os.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 49):

Assuming that list came from running `pyenv virtualenvs`, you should be able to run

```
pyenv uninstall 3.8.2/envs/greenhouse
```

to remove the `3.8.2/envs/greenhouse` environment.

The environments themselves should be subdirectories of whatever `pyenv root` returns when you run it. Try doing `cd $(pyenv root)` and then looking in the `versions/` and `versions/{version}/envs/` subdirectories.

See [the documentation for more details](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#delete-existing-virtualenv).

Answer (score 29):

You can also use:
`pyenv virtualenv-delete <venv-name>` - Delete Virtual Environment

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris)'s answer, you might also need to delete the local `.python-version`:

```
$ pyenv uninstall 3.8.12/envs/test_venv 
pyenv-virtualenv: remove /home/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/test_venv? (y/N) y
$ python -V
pyenv: version 'test_venv' is not installed (set by /home/user1/.python-version)
$ rm .python-version 
rm: remove regular file '.python-version'? y
$ python -V
Python 3.8.12
```