# Can I just delete the venv folder in django to delete virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I just want to check one thing, which is whether it is okay to delete a env folder. Other posts only discuss about how to remove it by code, or when the OS system is linux. I am trying to remove an old virtual env from a django project and just create a new one from the beginning. However, I am concerned if it is okay to just delete the venv folder through my windows file explorer. I have researched online, but I couldn't find a suitable and clear answer to this question. Thank you, and please leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah, you can just delete the virtual environment directory. It won't affect anything

Comment: Yes, you can just delete the folder like mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005457/how-do-i-remove-delete-a-virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just back up packages and their versions before you delete your virtual environment.

I suggest you to:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

*Delete your virtual environment.*

After creating a new one:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Sometimes it is a big problem to lose package versions. In terms of compatibility